# PHP Session multidimensional array not getting assigned any values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, session-variables

After a button is being pressed, 3 values are put in into a multidimensional array in PHP. I've checked the values before assigning in the same brackets and it seems to have the correct value. However, when I add the values like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['add_to_cart'])) {
    $count = count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);
    echo "Count: $count<br />";

    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$count]['product_id'] = $_POST['product_id'];
    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$count]['tier'] = $_POST['tier'];
    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$count]['division'] = $_POST['division'];
}
```

The output shows that the array `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']` is empty and has no values.

```
if (empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
    echo "Your cart is empty.<br />";
}
else {
    //Display products in cart
    foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
        echo $product['tier'] . $product['division'] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

I've came to the conclusion that I assign the values in a wrong way. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

EDIT:
forgot to add that the array is already initialized at the beginning!

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']` is never initialized like so:  `$_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array();`

Comment: @Will thanks for writing, I forgot to add that to the post, It's already initialized.

Comment: No prob. And you're also calling `session_start();`? I think we might need to see more of the code.

Comment: Wow that was it @Will Thanks so much for the help. It's my first day programming with PHP so I'm a beginner, going to add the answer to the question.

Comment: You should not use count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) as an index for its elements. If the cart has three items, 
$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$count]['product_id'] will try to get 
$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][3]['product_id'] which does not exist.

Comment: No problem :) I've had the same problem before. Also @dliche is right above. You'd want to use `$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$count - 1]` as `count(array())` will always be one larger than the last index.

Comment: @dliche Can you explain more? I know that it will always have one larger than the last index. But after I get the value through the count function, I assign new values to the array with the new index ($count variable) that didn't have any values. It's working perfectly fine for me. Even when I keep adding more and more items into the shopping cart.

Answer (score 3):

I forgot to add the `session_start();` to the code. That's why the Session array didn't work! Thanks for the help @Will

Comment: Yes, I was trying but can't until tomorrow since stackoverflow said that I can only accept my own answer after 2 days.